# C++ cannot name txt file after current sytem time and date

Tags: c++

Hi im having issue with this code i have made. It will compile but once i hit enter in the program it says this:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x008E8641 in Log Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x566D846A.
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cin.get();
    time_t Time;
    Time = time(0);
    string Date = __DATE__;

    string LOG = Time + "_" + Date;

    ofstream TEST;
    TEST.open(LOG);
    TEST << "This Text Should Appear Inside Of File.";
    TEST.close();
    cout << "Log has been Made.";
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I beleive that the problem is the time and how i tried putting it into a string but i dont see what i did doesn't work.

Comment: I think you need to convert `Time` to a string before you can concatenate it.

Comment: which OS? file naming conventions vary a lot.

Comment: @Dinesh What does that have to do with the error he's getting?

Comment: Also note that `__DATE__` will not give you the current date -- only the date on which the preprocessor was run.

Comment: In this line: `string LOG = Time + "_" + Date;` `Time` is most probably an integer type so `Time + "_"` is pointer arithmetic to somewhere random in memory.  You need to convert `Time` to a std::string first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that `Time` is an integer type so this:

```
Time + "_"
```

results in pointer addition so that what gets added to the string is a bad pointer to some location beyond the beginning of `"_"`.

You see string literals like `"_"` actually resolve to an address (pointer). Adding an integer like `Time` to it simple makes it point elsewhere in memory.

First you need to convert your `Time` to a string.

I happen to have this code laying around that may work for you:

```
std::string get_stamp()
{
    time_t t = std::time(0);
    char buf[sizeof("YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS")];
    return {buf, std::strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%F %H-%M-%S", std::localtime(&t))};
}
```

**Note:** Using `std::localtime` is not threas-safe.

Comment: Ahh this is nicer than my approach.  I would advise against putting colons in a filename though.  The format `"%F %H%M%S"` gets around that.  And beware that `localtime` is not thread-safe.

Comment: @paddy Both good points. Ive not coded for windows for years, didn't know about the colon. will fix

Comment: @Galik Thanks for the help, i should've converted the integer into a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you enabled compiler warnings, it should have screamed at you about this line:

```
string LOG = Time + "_" + Date;
```

Here, `Time` is being converted to a pointer, and you're getting undefined behaviour.  For a not completely C++ solution, I recommend this simple approach:

```
time_t t = time(0);
struct tm ttm;
localtime_r( &t, &ttm );

char timestamp[20];  // actually only need 17 chars plus terminator.
sprintf_s( timestamp, sizeof(timestamp), "%04d-%02d-%02d_%02d%02d%02d",
    ttm.tm_year + 1900, ttm.tm_mon + 1, ttm.tm_day, ttm.tm_hour, ttm.tm_min, ttm.tm_sec );

string logfilename = string(timestamp) + ".log";
ofstream logfile( logfilename.c_str() );
```

Note that `localtime_r` is not completely portable.  On windows, use `localtime_s`, which unfortunately also reverses the order of the arguments.

Comment: It's not unfortunate at all. It's a lovely little bit of vendor lock-in.

Comment: There is no pointer conversion. `Time` is an integer type. It is being added to a pointer, which is legal. If the program were run at January 1, 1970 at midnight, then there would be no UB.